# Lost option to use KDE after an update - how to bring it back without losing configuration

Tags: kubuntu, kdm

After running an update on Monday, on a Kubuntu 12.04 box, I've lost the option to select KDE in the login screen (there was a message that read approximately "option kde* has been removed"). Only "Default" and "Failsafe" remained. Using "Default" resulted in a black screen with only the KDE-style mouse cursor visible, using "Failsafe" brought me back to the login screen.

In the meantime, I've installed unity (and `gdm` along with it). I then attempted

```
sudo dpkg --reconfigure kdm
```

but that only brought back the KDE login screen (with additional GNOME/Unity session options). It looks like either some KDE package got uninstalled, or some configuration has been corrupted. Regarding the former:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep kde
apport-kde                  install
apturl-kde                  install
firefox-kde-support             install
gdebi-kde                   install
jockey-kde                  install
kde-baseapps-bin                install
kde-baseapps-data               install
kde-config-gtk                  install
kde-config-touchpad             install
kde-runtime                 install
kde-runtime-data                install
kde-style-oxygen                install
kde-wallpapers-default              install
kde-window-manager              install
kde-window-manager-common           install
kde-workspace-bin               deinstall
kde-workspace-data              install
kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins            install
kde-zeroconf                    install
kdebase-bin                 install
kdebase-runtime                 install
kdebase-runtime-data                deinstall
kdebase-workspace-bin               deinstall
kdebase-workspace-data              deinstall
kdegames-card-data              install
kdegraphics-libs-data               install
kdegraphics-mobipocket              install
kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer         install
kdegraphics-strigi-plugins          install
kdegraphics-thumbnailers            install
kdelibs-bin                 install
kdelibs5-data                   install
kdelibs5-plugins                install
kdemultimedia-kio-plugins           install
kdenetwork-filesharing              install
kdepasswd                   install
kdepim-groupware                deinstall
kdepim-kresources               install
kdepim-runtime                  install
kdepim-strigi-plugins               install
kdepimlibs-kio-plugins              install
kdesudo                     install
kdewallpapers                   install
language-pack-kde-en                install
language-pack-kde-en-base           install
language-selector-kde               install
libakonadi-kde4                 install
libdebconf-kde0                 install
libkde3support4                 install
libkdeclarative5                install
libkdecorations4                install
libkdecore5                 install
libkdegames5                    deinstall
libkdegames5a                   install
libkdepim4                  install
libkdepimdbusinterfaces4            install
libkdesu5                   install
libkdeui5                   install
libkdewebkit5                   install
libreoffice-kde                 install
polkit-kde-1                    install
python-kde4                 install
software-properties-kde             install
system-config-printer-kde           install
update-manager-kde              install
usb-creator-kde                 install
xsettings-kde                   install
```

I think some packages may be missing, but I'm not sure, and I don't want to experiment in fear of losing my KDE-specific configuration and/or making things worse.

In that vein: **How can I restore the KDE option on login without losing my configuration?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe some KDE package got removed?

Try `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: * facepalm *. Yes, turns out it was kubuntu-desktop and kde-workspace-bin . There really needs to be a more prominent warning that packages are deleted during an update...